psycopg2 - ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _psycopg: The specified module could not be found
I tried to install psycopg2 under Pycharm editor using python 3.13 and psycopg2-binary 2.9.10.
I got this error:
Traceback (most recent call last):File "...\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\database.py", 
line 1, in <module>import psycopg2File "...\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\Lib\site-
packages\psycopg2_init_.py", line 51, in <module>from psycopg2._psycopg import (                     
# noqa...<10 lines>...)ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _psycopg: The specified module could not be found.

I tried the following attempts:

pip install --force-reinstall psycopg2-binary
I installed Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable
I recreated Virtual Environment and the psycopg2-binary library

Why this issue occure and how to resolve it?

Add Python 3.13 packages for Windows #1736.

Have you installed libpq? It is a runtime dependency for psycopg2-binary that is not installed/managed by python/pip. See https://www.psycopg.org/docs/install.html#runtime-requirements and

@Dunes, from the docs Installation: The psycopg2-binary package is meant for beginners to start playing with Python and PostgreSQL without the need to meet the build requirements. [...] The binary packages come with their own versions of a few C libraries, among which libpq and libssl,

Right, so the answer is one of: (1) use python < 3.13 , or (2) install psycopg2  (instead of psycopg2-binary) from source, or (3) wait for the new version to released.

Right what? You said libpq needs  to be separately installed for pyscop2-binary and that is not the case, it is included.
